# unrecognized selector sent to instance of custom class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Here is class header:

```
@interface ChallengeItem : NSObject 
.......
- (NSString *) getAlertIntervalInString;
- (void) createReminder;

@end

some implementation in .m file:

- (NSString *) getAlertIntervalInString {
... do something
}

- (void)createReminder {
... do something
}
```

I call

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self count]; i++) {
    ChallengeItem *currentItem = [self getChallengeAtIndex:i];
    if (currentItem.isStarted) {
        [currentItem createReminder];
    }
}
```

and receive an unrecognized selector error, but when I change

```
[currentItem createReminder];
```

to

```
[currentItem getAlertIntervalInString];
```

error isn't appear.
What is the problem?

Here is the console log

> Current language:  auto; currently objective-c 2011-11-23 00:56:40.056
>   30 Day Challenge[379:12b03] -[ChallengeItem createReminder]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6079900 2011-11-23
>   00:56:40.147 30 Day Challenge[379:12b03] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[ChallengeItem createReminder]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6079900'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb35a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01107313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fb50bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f24966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f24522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   30 Day Challenge                    0x00006950 -[ChallengeCollection setRemindersForStartedChallenges] + 144
    6   30 Day Challenge                    0x00002f27 -[_0_Day_ChallengeAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:] + 151
    7   UIKit                               0x00209a40 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 607
    8   UIKit                               0x00213039 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 4127
    9   UIKit                               0x0020aabf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    10  UIKit                               0x0020ff2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x01712992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00f94944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef4cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef1f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef1840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00ef1761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x017111c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x01711289 GSEventRun + 115
    19  UIKit                               0x00213c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    20  30 Day Challenge                    0x00002059 main + 121
    21  30 Day Challenge                    0x00001fd5 start + 53
    22  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

Comment: Can we see the actual crash log from the console?

Comment: show code for getChallengeAtIndex

Comment: - (ChallengeItem *)getChallengeAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
 return [self.challenges objectAtIndex:index];
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious problems with your code.  To make sure `getChallengeAtIndex` is in fact returning `ChallengeItem` instances, you could put a breakpoint at that line and inspect the returned values.

Comment: I'll check it, getChallengeAtIndex return normal instance. If I change function createReminder to some already implemented, it works, but if I call createReminder or add something new function to class it causes error :(

Answer (score 0):

After you install the new version of XCode, the problem will be gone.